# How to remove a selected attribute from option A and then re-apply to option B on change?

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

**Desired Behaviour**

Remove existing `selected` attribute from Option A (if it exists) and apply `selected` attribute to Option B.

**Current Behaviour**

Current attempt works on first change, but on subsequent changes continues adding the selected attribute to the selected options so that there is more than one option with a selected attribute.

**Constraints**

HTML structure and selector defined below, ie `.my_div`, are required.

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/e7teL39u/

**HTML**

```
<div class="my_div">
<select>
    <option value="none">none</option>
    <option value="val1">val1</option>
    <option value="val2">val2</option>
    <option value="val3">val3</option>
    <option value="val4">val4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("change",".my_div", function() {
// remove old selected attribute - this doesn't enable solution
// $(this).find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');

// apply selected attribute to new selection
var new_selection = $(this).find('option:selected');
new_selection.attr("selected",true); 
});
```

Comment: As only one options can be selected, you don't need to worry about deselecting anything - just select the required option.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing so? The `selected` attribute is often only use upon page load, when the browser has to decide which default option to display in the select element.

Comment: Besides, it's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. The selected attribute looks after itself.

Comment: Not sure about purpose, too... but this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/e7teL39u/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one worked fine:

```
var new_selection = $(this).find('option:selected');
$('option').not(new_selection).removeAttr('selected');
new_selection.attr("selected",true);
```

Comment: It's not necessary to create a jQuery collection of every ``<option>`` in the document and remove ``selected`` for each one. You should only capture what needs to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).on("change",".my_div", function() {
// remove old selected attribute - this doesn't enable solution
// $(this).find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');

// apply selected attribute to new selection
$(".selected").removeAttr("selected");
var new_selection = $(this).find('option:selected');
new_selection.attr("selected",true).addClass(".selected"); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on lvil's answer, the reason it works is because `option:selected` captures the actual selected `<option>` rather than the one with the `selected` attribute, which would be `option[selected]`. My solution uses more appropriate selectors instead of scanning the entire document for `<option>` elements:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.my_div', function () {
  // remove old selected attributes only in .my_div
  $('.my_div').find('option[selected]').removeAttr('selected');
  // apply selected attribute to new selection only in .my_div
  $('.my_div').find('option:selected').attr('selected', true);

  updateValues();
});

updateValues();

// below here is just to demonstrate output and is not required in this answer
function updateValues() {
  var my_option = $('.my_div option[selected]').get(0),
      other_option = $('.other_div option[selected]').get(0);

  if(my_option) {
    $('#my_option').text(my_option.outerHTML);
  } else {
    $('#my_option').text('none selected');
  }
  
  if(other_option) {
    $('#other_option').text(other_option.outerHTML);
  } else {
    $('#other_option').text('none selected');
  }
}
```

```css
/* easier to read */
html {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my_div">
    my_div: 
    <select>
        <option value="none">none</option>
        <option value="val1">val1</option>
        <option value="val2">val2</option>
        <option value="val3">val3</option>
        <option value="val4">val4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<!-- below here is just to demonstrate output and is not required in this answer -->

<!-- outputs element in .my_div with selected attribute ([selected], not :selected) -->
<div id="my_option"></div>
<!-- another select element to demonstrate lack of interference with other options -->
<div class="other_div">
  other select:
  <select>
      <option value="none">none</option>
      <option value="val1">val1</option>
      <option value="val2">val2</option>
      <option value="val3" selected="selected">val3</option>
      <option value="val4">val4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!-- outputs element in .other_div with selected attribute ([selected], not :selected) -->
<div id="other_option"></div>
```