# How to toggle selected true or false onchange of select tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-select

I have a select tag with n-number of options. I need to set the selected option to true and set others to false. The true should toggle when the onchange function triggers.

My code is below:

```
let techDropClone = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
let opt = techDropClone.options;
opt[techDropClone.selectedIndex].setAttribute("selected",true);
```

I know that the above code will not toggle the true but I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a selected attribute from option A and then re-apply to option B on change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676680/how-to-remove-a-selected-attribute-from-option-a-and-then-re-apply-to-option-b-o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a vanilla js solution could be:

```
let techDropClone = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
let opt = techDropClone.options;

for(var i=0; i<opt.length; i++){
    if(i == techDropClone.selectedIndex){
        opt[i].setAttribute("selected",true);
    }else{
        opt[i].setAttribute("selected",false);
    }
}
```

Optimizations are possible, but i don't know well enough your data structure

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way:

```js
function myfunc(el){
  document.querySelectorAll('select option').forEach(function(op){
    op.removeAttribute("selected");
  });
  let techDropClone = el;
  let opt = techDropClone.options;
  opt[techDropClone.selectedIndex].setAttribute("selected", true);
}

myfunc(document.querySelector('select'));
```

```html
<select onchange="myfunc(this)">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

$('button').on('click', function() { var chbx = $('input[type=checkbox]');$.each(chbx, function( index, value ) {console.log(value.id+':'+value.checked);});});

Comment: It seems he is not using jQuery